# search for the average via streamapi

Tags: java, java-stream

how to use the api stream to find the average grade in a given subject for all students?
Allow in Hashmap<String, String > map

For example: `key: "Ann", value: "Physics 3.5 Math 4.0 History 2.5"`

```
class Student {

    private String name;
    private Map<String, List<Integer>> marks;


    public Student(String name, Map<String, List<Integer>> marks) {
        this.name = name;
        this.marks = marks;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Map<String, List<Integer>> getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, List<Integer>> markAnn = new HashMap<>();
        markAnn.put("Physics", List.of(4, 4, 5));
        markAnn.put("Mathematics", List.of(2, 3, 4));
        markAnn.put("History", List.of(3, 3, 3));

        Map<String, List<Integer>> markKate = new HashMap<>();
        markKate.put("Physics", List.of(1, 2, 3));
        markKate.put("Mathematics", List.of(5, 5, 3));
        markKate.put("History", List.of(4, 2, 5));

        Student[] students = {new Student("Ann", markAnn),
                new Student("Kate", markKate)
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: you seem to want the average of every subject for every student instead of "average grade in a given subject for all students". Is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

As I understood you need a method that`s finds all averages in subjects for student. So you can create method like findAverage:

```
 public static Map<String, List<Integer>> findAverage(Map<String, List<Integer>> students){
        return students.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        Map.Entry::getKey,
                        entry -> Collections.singletonList(
                                (int) entry.getValue().stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).average().orElse(0)
                        )
                ));
    }
```

The method returns Map<String, List> with value like:

```
{Mathematics=[4], History=[3], Physics=[2]}
```

than you can add it to your collection.

```
Student[] students = {new Student("Ann", findAverage(markAnn)),
                new Student("Kate", findAverage(markKate))
        };
```

Note that could be some situations when the average could be 4.3 or 3.5. So if you need it. You can change types to double whenever you want by using `mapToDouble()` instead `mapToInt()`

Comment: It doesn't need to be changed in all places. Just use `mapToDouble()`.

Comment: Yep, i forgot about it, thanks. I will update answer